# Nonnegative derivative bounded by function, show that $f$ is zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm struggling to prove the following statement, which makes intuitive sense:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Suppose $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad 0 \le f'(x) \le f(x)\,$. If $f$ vanishes at some point, show that $f$ is identically zero.

This is exercise 6 in section 6.7, in *Elementary Classical Analysis* by Mardsen & Hofmann.

I've managed to do the following:

Let $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ be the point such that $f(\omega) = 0$ (which exists by hypothesis). Let $x < \omega$. By Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem,

$$
\exists \xi \in (x, \omega)\colon\quad 0 \le f(x) =f(x) - f(\omega) = f'(\xi)(x - \omega)\,.
$$

By hypothesis, we have that $f'(\xi) \ge 0$. On the other hand, $x - \omega < 0$. Thus, $f'(\xi)(x - \omega) \le 0$. By the above proposition, though, $ f'(\xi)(x - \omega) \ge 0\,$. Therefore, $f'(\xi) = 0$ which implies $f(x) = 0$.

With this we have proven that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\quad x \le \omega \rightarrow f(x) = 0\,$.

But for $x > \omega$, I haven't been able to prove much. I've got so far:

Let $x > \omega$. By Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem,

$$
\exists \xi_1 \in (\omega, x)\colon\quad 0 \le f(x) = f(x) - f(\omega) = f'(\xi_1)(x - \omega) \le f(\xi_1)(x - \omega)\,.
$$

If we apply this reasoning recursively on $f(\xi_1)$, we get a succession $(\xi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq (\omega, x)$ such that $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}\quad \xi_{i+1} \in (\omega, \xi_i)$ and

$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\quad f(x) \le f(\xi_n) \prod_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (\xi_i - \omega)
$$

where $\xi_0 = x$.

Is there a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to see that if $f \neq 0$, then there exists $y>\omega$ such taht $\forall x \geq y, f(x)>0$. For such an $x$ you have $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\leq 1$. You can integrate and this gives $f(x) \leq e^x$, thus giving an hint to introduce the function $g(x)\doteq f(x)e^{-x}$. You can work from that point.

Answer (score 3):

$(e^{-x}f(x))'=e^{-x}(f'(x)-f(x)) \leq 0$ so $e^{-x}f(x)$ is decreasing. If $f(x_o)=0$ then $e^{-x}f(x)$ is non-negative and $\leq e^{-x_0}f(x_0) =0$ for $x>x_0$ so $f(x)=0$ for $x \geq x_0$. For $x \leq x_0$ you already have a proof.